# How to set PDF paragraph or font line-height with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, css

How can I change the line-height of a PDF font or paragraph using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Line spacing in terms of typography is called leading.  If you can use line spacing, you can use Paragraph.Leading or Paragraph.LeadingMultiplier.  See http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch02.html#phrase

Comment: thanks, using my version (4.1.6) paragraph.Leading = 12f; solved me problems :)

Answer (score 7):

paragraph.SetLeading(X, Y) where X - is fixed leading and Y is leading multiplayer. Leading is space between two text baselines. Final leading value is calculated like: X+Y*max font size in row.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure in what context your text is in, but I have mine in a PdfCell and I used MinimumHeight and PaddingTop:

```
cAddr = new PdfPCell(ptAddr);
cAddr.MinimumHeight = 101.0F;
cAddr.PaddingTop = 30;
```